# Extracting ints and shorts from a struct using AVX?

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, avx

I have a struct which contains a union between various data members and an AVX type to load all the bytes in one load. My code looks like:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

union S{
    struct{
        int32_t a;
        int32_t b;
        int16_t c;
        int16_t d;
    };

    __m128i x;
}
```

I'd like to use the AVX register to load the data all together and then separately extract the four members in to `int32_t` and `int16_t` local variables.

How would I go about doing this? I am unsure how I can separate the data members from each other when extracting from the AVX register?

EDIT: Was looking for answers in terms of GCC intrinsics.

EDIT2: Have updated the code to swap struct with union.

Comment: Aw c'mon. `pextrw` and `pextrd` (Packed Extract Word/Doubleword) are your friends here. You want the 0th DWORD, 1st DWORD, 4th WORD and 5th WORD. ***EDIT:*** `int _mm_extract_epi16 ( __m128i a, int imm)` and `int _mm_extract_epi32 (__m128i src, const int ndx)`

Comment: Are you saying to do this I need to write inline x86? There's no GCC intrinsics for this?

Comment: Also, why AVX if you're just using `__m128i` ?

Comment: @PaulR I believe OP may have inadvertently swapped `union` and `struct`; He may have meant to make a `union S` that makes overlap a `__m128i` and an irregular `struct`, as opposed to a `struct S` of 16+4 bytes.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: aha - that would make sense!

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to use the data members to extract various parts of a 128 bit register, via the union. To be honest, if I was writing all four data members together I probably wouldn't even need the individual data members?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extract 16 bit elements from an `__m128i` using `_mm_extract_epi16` (requires SSE2):

```
int16_t v = _mm_extract_epi16 (v, 4);  // extract element 4
```

For 32 bit elements use `_mm_extract_epi32` (requires SSE4.1)

```
int32_t v = _mm_extract_epi32 (v, 0);  // extract element 0
```

See: [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html)

---

Assuming your struct is declared as:

```
union S{
    struct{
        int32_t a;
        int32_t b;
        int16_t c;
        int16_t d;
    };

    __m128i x;
}
```

then you would extract elements a, b, c, d as follows:

```
S s = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };

__m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&s);

int32_t a = _mm_extract_epi32 (v, 0);
int32_t b = _mm_extract_epi32 (v, 1);
int16_t c = _mm_extract_epi16 (v, 4);
int16_t d = _mm_extract_epi16 (v, 5);
```

Comment: I wonder how the efficiency of `_mm_extract_epi32(v,0)` compares to `_mm_cvtsi128_si32(v)`. Maybe the compiler converts `_mm_extract_epi32(v,0)` to `_mm_cvtsi128_si32(v)` anyway?

Comment: Not much difference, I would think - `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` is available on SSE2 of course, but it only works for element 0. Take your pick! ;-)

Comment: Fair point, I guess it's splitting hairs. I personally have never found a need to use anything more than `_mm_cvtsi128_si32(v)` and if I did need `_mm_extract_epi32` then I'm probably doing something wrong.