# Union class members with AVX register to reduce memory accesses?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, avx

If I have a class (or struct) containing a mixture of pointers, floats, doubles, int32s and int16s, can I union the class with an AVX register and then access the data via the union to force the compiler to load the data all together?

I am trying to reduce memory loads.

Comment: That sounds like quite a lot of data in the structure, much more than could fit in a single AVX register.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva the compiler doesn't know my access pattern :)

Comment: Perhaps you can post your structure declaration, at least without member names?

Comment: How is your new question different from the [old one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105513/extracting-ints-and-shorts-from-a-struct-using-avx)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, and it will work (if struct is small enough), but it won't be faster at the end.
Except for the case when you want to just copy the whole struct as a 32-byte chunk.

If you load all the members separately, then you'll see many load instructions like `mov eax, [esi + 10h]` in assembly. It seems that you want to reduce number of these instructions.

You can indeed load them as one AVX value of type `__m256`, then you'll see only one instruction like `vmovaps ymm0, [esi]`. However, the result of that load will be in a 256-bit YMM register. You won't be able to access parts of this register for free.

XMM and YMM registers mostly act as big chunks of data, you can easily do 8-wide addition of 32-bit integers, but you cannot quickly access arbitrary parts of these 256-bit chunks. You can still try to extract parts of a YMM register, but it would require additional instructions (at least as many as number of `mov`-s in the scalar version), so the resulting code would be slower.

If you really want to extract parts of AVX register, be sure to use `#pragma pack` on your struct and align its data members manually, because otherwise offsets of the members can vary depending on compiler and bitness.

The other thing you might care about is the number of actual memory transactions. You might think that one 256-bit load is faster than many separate 32-bit and 16-bit loads. In my opinion this is not true: memory is operated on cache line granularity. Each 64-byte block of memory is a single cache line, and processor can only load the whole cache line. In both cases the same number of cache lines would be loaded, so memory accesses won't get faster.

Comment: gcc isn't very smart at copying multiple members at once of structs (this is a known regression since gcc 2.95 or something), so there's potentially a gain if you're copying around structs with byte members, esp. if they're in L1 cache.  L1 cache can handle 2 loads and one store per clock on Haswell and later, so most of the time that's not the bottleneck.  To saturate main-memory bandwidth with one core of a ~3GHz CPU, you need to load something like 8B / clock.

Comment: Using a union with a vector type to make copying whole structs faster is maybe viable.  Loading and then doing `PEXTRD` / `PEXTRW` / etc. to get individual members out into general-purpose registers will be slower than loading the members from memory as needed.  At https://github.com/pcordes/par2-asm-experiments, I have various asm routines for doing 16b LUT lookups with index = each byte of a source buffer.  (For a GF16 multiply for par2.)  I found loading the source buffer into 64bit GP registers, and shifting that to get a the bytes, was the way to go. Near saturating LUT load and uop tput.